# How can I specify the user agent of a device in a web app utilizing WKWebView in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I have been trying to figure out how to specify a user agent for my web app in Swift 4 so that the website it opens is in mobile-view. It is defaulting to desktop view instead of mobile. Is there any way to fix this? I am currently learning Swift so I am not that familiar with it yet. I have attached the code below, changing the website for confidentiality reasons.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var website = "https://www.example.com"
    @IBOutlet var webpage: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: website)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webpage.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change your user agent adding the following HTTPHeaderField:

```
// valid only for this request
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")!)
request.addValue("myUserAgent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
```

---

Another possibility which will completely override the default user agent (might be harmful) is this:

```
wkWebView.customUserAgent = "myUserAgent"
```